# Difference between sudo -u $USER and su - $USER as non root user

Tags: bash, shell, sudo, su

How come the first one doesn't work and is not able to find `conda` on the *PATH* and the second works?

```
$ su - $NB_USER -c "echo $PATH && conda --version"
/opt/conda/condabin:/opt/conda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
-sh: 1: conda: not found
$ sudo -u $NB_USER -- echo $PATH && conda --version
/opt/conda/condabin:/opt/conda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
conda 4.9.2
```

Comment: In both commands, the `$PATH` value is from the interactive shell invoking `su` and `sudo`, not from the shell actually trying to invoke `conda`.  This is due to the quoting with double quotes (1st command) and non-quoting (2nd command) of the command. In the second command, you don't even execute `conda` with `sudo` (the `sudo` command ends at `&&`). You may want to try `sudo -u "$NB_USER" sh -c 'echo $PATH && conda --version'` or something similar (I don't have `sudo` on my machine so can't test properly).

Comment: This is the correct answer, you should make it into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am making [@Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116858/kusalananda)'s comment into a community answer, so that is question won't remain unanswered.

In both commands, the `$PATH` value is from the interactive shell invoking `su` and `sudo`, not from the shell actually trying to invoke `conda`. This is due to the quoting with double quotes (1st command) and non-quoting (2nd command) of the command. In the second command, you don't even execute `conda` with `sudo` (the `sudo` command ends at `&&`). You may want to try `sudo -u "$NB_USER" sh -c 'echo $PATH && conda --version'` or something similar (I don't have `sudo` on my machine so can't test properly).

Comment: Thanks! I don't use `sudo` or Linux, so I didn't have any way of testing.